# Проверка "постов низкого качества". Странное поведение

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано

Обратил внимание, что после проверки и редактирования т.н. "постов низкого качетсва" (видимо, просто слишком коротких по мнению движка), они снова попадают мне же на проверку. Довольно забавная ситуация, особенно если учесть, что если пост просто пропущен или одобрен, этого не происходит. Если уж так необходима повторная проверка после моего редактирования, то это должен делать кто-то другой. А то получается, что я должен одобрить свою же правку. Или держать пост у себя в очереди пока кто-то меня не выручит. Как-то не верится, что это задумка такая, а не глюк...